# Predefined read permission not working solr

Tags: solr, permissions, basic-authentication, roles

I want to make read permission for "Tom" user to only make queries. but when I test as following 
`curl -u tom:TomIsCool http://localhost:8983/solr/mysql_core/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'`

still I can create, delete, update.

my security.json file

```
  "authentication": {
    "blockUnknown": true,
    "class": "solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials": {
      "solr": "IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c=",
      "tom": "iaEw3JVJuEQjnFnd/vhey7bDtOSF/lH90QQDTF7gTjg= nBEjpSfhXZxpCrtyePRkuX0D3R9KTU2BPXhvOCUUmNE="
    },
    "": { "v": 0 }
  },
  "authorization": {
    "class": "solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "name": "security-edit",
        "role": "admin",
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "read",
        "role": "guest",
        "index": 2
      }
    ],
    "user-role": {
      "solr": "admin",
      "tom": "guest"
    },
    "": { "v": 0 }
  }
}
```

How I can accomplish that? should I use different permission?

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure, that you restarted Solr after changed the security.json?

Comment: did you manage to set this up? I'm dealing with the exact same problem.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. is there a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it was you who asked a similar question [here](https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin-question-td4434198.html), but the short answer seems to be:

> One important thing to remember about the RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin
> is that if it doesn't find any rules matching a particular API call,
> it will allow the request.